# How can I create a salesforce workflow rule in a html/js mobile app?

Tags: workflow

Does anybody knows how can I create a salesforce workflow rule in a html/js mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

It took me sometime to figure out, but I was able to do this using the metadata api:

```
<apex:page >
<script>
    function createWorkflow()
    {
        // Calls the Metdata API from JavaScript to create the Remote Site Setting to permit Apex callouts
        var binding = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var request =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'+
                '<env:Header>' +
                    '<urn:SessionHeader xmlns:urn="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                        '<urn:sessionId>{!$Api.Session_ID}</urn:sessionId>' +
                    '</urn:SessionHeader>' +
                '</env:Header>' +
                '<env:Body>' +
                    '<createMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                        '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:Workflow" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                            '<fullName>Opportunity</fullName>' +
                            '<fieldUpdates>' +
                                '<fullName>Update_Close_Date_On_Closed_Won</fullName>' +
                                '<description>Update Close Date on Closed Won</description>' +
                                '<field>CloseDate</field>' +
                                '<formula>TODAY()</formula>' +
                                '<name>Update Close Date on Closed Won</name>' +
                                '<notifyAssignee>false</notifyAssignee>' +
                                '<operation>Formula</operation>' +
                                '<protected>false</protected>' +
                            '</fieldUpdates>' +
                            '<rules>' +
                                '<fullName>On Opportunity Closed Won</fullName>' +
                                '<active>true</active>' +
                                '<actions>' +
                                    '<name>Update_Close_Date_On_Closed_Won</name>' +
                                    '<type>FieldUpdate</type>' +
                                '</actions>' +
                                '<criteriaItems>' +
                                    '<field>Opportunity.StageName</field>' +
                                    '<operation>equals</operation>' +
                                    '<value>Closed Won</value>' +
                                '</criteriaItems>' +
                                '<description>On Opportunity Closed Won update the CloseDate field on Opportunity</description>' +
                                '<triggerType>onCreateOrTriggeringUpdate</triggerType>' +
                            '</rules>'+
                        '</metadata>' +
                    '</createMetadata>' +
                '</env:Body>' +
            '</env:Envelope>';
        binding.open('POST', '/services/Soap/m/31.0');
        binding.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction','""');
        binding.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        binding.onreadystatechange =
            function() {
                if(this.readyState==4) {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var doc  = parser.parseFromString(this.response, 'application/xml');
                    var errors = doc.getElementsByTagName('errors');
                    var messageTxt = '';

                    console.log('response = ', this.response);
                    console.log('status = ', this.status);
                    console.log('statusText = ', this.statusText);

                    for(var errorIdx = 0; errorIdx < errors.length; errorIdx++)
                        messageTxt += errors.item(errorIdx).getElementsByTagName('message').item(0).innerHTML + '\n';

                    console.log('messageTxt = ', messageTxt);
                }
            }
        binding.send(request);
    }
</script>

<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="createWorkflow();" value="Create Workflow"></input>
```

When you click on the Create Workflow button, a workflow for Opportunity alongwith its field update is created in the org.

You can refer to http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Metadata API. Docs represents here -https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_workflow.htm